# How to add rows only if it doesn't exists in the df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list which looks like this:

```
[2,4,3,1,5]  # One to Five in a certain order
```

I have a df that looks like this

```
ID    Name    Address
1      A         ABC
3      B         DEF
```

I want to add which ever IDs are missing with the values being False for Name and Address (there are a lot of columns towards to right, I don't want to manually give false for it, so if there is a method that will fill False for rest of the columns then its better)

After adding it, I want the DF to be sorted based on the order of the list.

Expected result:

```
ID   Name    Address
2    False      False
4    False      False
3    B          DEF
1    A          ABC
5    False      False
```

Comment: Can you please show what you at least tried? There are multiple ways of doing this

Comment: I am pretty new to pandas, just learning things. I couldn't do much

Comment: What steps do you think might be relevant, though? If you don't try to think your way through the problem then the answer (which I predict will come within 2 minutes) doesn't make you consider anything and diminishes from your learning

Comment: I think pd.concat will work after converting the list to a df. But how to only take the needed rows and fill in False for others + sorting it. i have no clue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting your initial df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 3],
                   'Name': ['A', 'B'],
                   'Address': ['ABC', 'DEF']})
print(df.head()
```

It's useful to note here that an integer index is made for you. The way you list your `df` doesn't show such an index. The required output suggests that `'ID'` is the index but it's not totally clear how you want the output in that format.

The first thing to do is set the index as `'ID'`:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
```

Then you can [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) that to build a backbone of the resulting df, which will fill the remaining columns with `NaN`.

```
df = df.set_index('ID').reindex(index=lst)
```

Gives:

```
  Name Address
ID             
2   NaN     NaN
4   NaN     NaN
3     B     DEF
1     A     ABC
5   NaN     NaN
```

(Note that `'ID'`, being the index, is now on a different level to the other column names)

The final step is to [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `False`

Putting it together:

```
df = df.set_index('ID').reindex(index=lst).fillna(False).reset_index()
```

The last `reset_index()` is optional because, as I said, you don't appear to have an independent index in your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this:

```
your_list = [2,4,3,1,5]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[False]*len(your_list), 'Address':[False]*len(your_list)}, index=your_list)

df1.loc[df.index] = df
```

where `df` is the sample dataframe with two rows.